# jQuery count div by class and then get the inner div's id string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to count the total div by class name and then get the specific part of inner div's id. Here is my example,

```
<div class=”my_block1”>
    <div class=”my_block2”>
        <div id=”my-style-35-area”>
            some contents
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class=”my_block1”>
    <div class=”my_block2”>
        <div id=”my-style-36-area”>
            some contents
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class=”my_block1”>
    <div class=”my_block2”>
        <div id=”my-style-38-area”>
            some contents
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, I need to figure out that 35, 36, 38 from the ID's. Anyone can help me with this please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying to count the number of my_block or my-style-<number>-area or does it not matter

Comment: to get the count : $('.my_block1').length

Comment: actually I need to count the number of my_block1 div and then figure out the part of the inner div's id. Thanks for your question.

Comment: Question shows a lack of research. Counting elements is not hard to research. If you have done some research and made code attempts but got stuck, you should show those attempts. This isn't a free coding service

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl , I tried with $(".my_block1").length to figure out the number of my div element, but failed to parse the string within it.

Comment: ok... so always include what you have so it shows you made attempts. You will get much more help when people see you tried vs looking like you want someone else to do all the work for you. Also you will learn more when mistakes are pointed out

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of div with a specific class:

```
$('.my_block1').length // would give you 3
```

and to get the ids inside that div :

```
$('.my_block1').find('[id^=my-style-]').each(function()
{
   alert(this.id.split('-')[2]); // give you the ids of each div
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/ytzLgx0q/

Answer (score 0):

You can get `35, 36, 38` in an array using `map()` function like following.

```
var num = $('div[id^="my-style-"]').map(function () {
    return this.id.split('-')[2];
}).get();
console.log(num
```

BTW in you html you have used `”` instead of `"`.

Comment: I don't think you need div appended on the selector since the id is good enough.

Comment: @DinoMyte not always about just being good enough to find it .. performance might also have been considered. An attribute selector alone requires searching all elements in dom

Comment: @charlietfl: Thanks for pointing that out. will keep in mind :)

Comment: @DinoMyte of course a perf test would be best .... i was just throwing it out there but would make sense that filtering `div` first would be more performant